# SSL Pinning with AFNetworking - validatesCertificateChain = true

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to make a pinning SSL with AFNetworking 2.5.4 (with a Comodo Certificate). 
I grab my certificate (CER) from the server.

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts
```

Grab the output between the first -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- and save it to example.pem

Convert from PEM to CER (DER):

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in example.pem -out example.cer
```

Then, i add example.cer to my Xcode project and i add it to the 'Copy Bundle Resources' Build Phase. My SecurityPolicy are:

```
let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.PublicKey)
    let certificatePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example", ofType: "cer")!
    let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: certificatePath)!

    securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = [certificateData];

    securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = true
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = false
    securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = false

    manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy
```

With this SSL Pininning works but I want not only validate the leaf certificate for that i change

```
securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = true
```

But with that configuration throws me the following error:

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

I have read if securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = true i must enter the entire SSL certificate chain but I do not know how to generate it.

I tried with following code but not work (i get the same error):

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > example.cer
```

How do I get the entire SSL certificate chain for add to Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

You got to also add all Intermediate CA Certs to securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates to validate the entire chain.

Comment: I tried to add intermediate CA Certs but I don't work it. How do i add the intermediate CA Certs correctly?

Comment: The purpose of pinning is to prevent MIMT, and also complete ignore the risks associated with trusting CA's like Comodo not to get compromised.  So maybe in this case, since you are pinning the Public key, you should not validate cert chain. You should set securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = false. Another thing is to make sure your domain name is same on your cert and the server you are connecting to.  You may be able to test by setting securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false.

Comment: do i not understand why the validatesCertificateChain should be false if to avoid MIMT should validate the certificate chain? and the validatesDomainName should be true for validate that server and client is same?

Comment: Because you pinned the server cert into our app, you just need to validate against the server cert that was sent to you by the server to make sure is same.  No need to check signatures.

Comment: I mean no need to check the chain of trust.

Comment: You really have to understand how mitm works in order to know why pinning can guard against it.